# Excel Loop VBA incrementing rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops

Hi I have a section of code that I am trying to write a loop for but I am struggling with how to go about it.

This portion of the code runs fine. But I actually have 4 cells which are the ranges, C26,  C91, C156 and C221. (See Container 1 comment in code)

I managed to get it to loop, but then my references below (e.g B33,C33,D33,etc.) just write over the top. Is there anyway to write a loop that can increment all of the successive code by the required 65 rows??

I really want to learn how to do this properly rather than copying and pasting 4 times and manually updating the references!

```
Private Sub RunStabSetup()


' Confirmation of Entry to Form

If MsgBox("Have you double checked your data is correct and ALL test points have been selected before entering on the spreadsheet?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.Worksheets("Req Sheet").Range("C83") = " "

If Container1CB.Value > "" Then

'Container 1

    Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("C26") = Container1CB

  '60° CheckBox logic statements

    If W1T60.Value = True Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("B33") = "1"
    If W1T60.Value = False Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("B33") = ""

    If W2T60.Value = True Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("C33") = "2"
    If W2T60.Value = False Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("C33") = ""

    If W3T60.Value = True Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("D33") = "3"
    If W3T60.Value = False Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("D33") = ""

    If W4T60.Value = True Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("E33") = "4"
    If W4T60.Value = False Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("E33") = ""

    If W5T60.Value = True Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("F33") = "5"
    If W5T60.Value = False Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("F33") = ""

    If W6T60.Value = True Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("G33") = "6"
    If W6T60.Value = False Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("G33") = ""

    If W7T60.Value = True Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("H33") = "7"
    If W7T60.Value = False Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("H33") = ""

    If W8T60.Value = True Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("I33") = "8"
    If W8T60.Value = False Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Range("I33") = ""
 End If

End Sub
```

Thanks for you help everyone!

Comment: Will the `W1T60` values keep incrementing too? I assume that you want B33 = 1, C33 = 2, and if we went to like, Z33, you'd want Z33 = 25?

Answer (score 1):

I'd make it like:

```
i=2
do while i<= maxColumn 
        If W1T60.Value = True Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Cells(i,33).Value2 = i-1
        If W1T60.Value = False Then Application.Worksheets("StabDataCapture").Cells(i,33).Value2 = ""
loop
```

from your code I don't see how to change the Cells(i,**j**) parameter, so I left it constant, but with similar logic you can modify it

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you can do this using for loops and the offset feature. I would probably do it by first defining your range as an array of ranges. `Dim rng(0 to 3) as Range` and then defining each of your 4 cells in column C.

```
Set rng(0) = Range("C26")
Set rng(1) = Range("C91")
Set rng(2) = Range("C156")
Set rng(3) = Range("C221")
```

Then you can enclose your "if" statement in a for each loop.

```
Dim c As Variant
For Each c In rng
    if Container1CB.Value > "" Then

        Sheets("StabDataCapture").c.Value = Container1CB

        If W1T60.Value = True Then Sheets("StabDataCapture").c.Offset(7,-1).Value = "1"
        If W1T60.Value = False Then sheets("StabDataCapture").c.Offset(7,-1).Value = ""

        If W2T60.Value = True Then sheets("StabDataCapture").c.Offset(7,0).Value = "2"
        If W2T60.Value = False Then sheets("StabDataCapture").c.Offset(7,0).Value = ""

....

end if
```

Alternatively, you could use a for loop like `For i = 0 to 65*4 Step 65` and you could replace statements like `Range("C26")` with `Cells(i,3).Value`

To set each value in your "IF-THEN" statements, your best solution again is probably an array. `Dim WT(1 To 8) as Variant` and then you can set each value of the array equal to the value of W1T60, W2T60, etc. `WT(1) = W1T60.Value`. Then the code can be updated to:

```
Dim c As Variant
Dim i as Integer
For Each c In rng
    if Container1CB.Value > "" Then

        Sheets("StabDataCapture").c.Value = Container1CB

        For i = 1 To 8
            If WT(i) Then 
                Sheets("StabDataCapture").c.Offset(7, i - 2).Value = i
            else
                Sheets("StabDataCapture").c.Offset(7, i - 2).Value = ""
            end if
        next i

    End If
Next
```